# Open xml 2.5 find a specific placeholder with specific fieldcode. C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, backend, openxml-sdk

`enter code here`I have a problem. I created a specific property in word called OrderLines and it contains a row of three cells. I want to clone that line and then I want to go into the clone and change all three table cells FieldCode that has a property Text. In that property, I want to change that has n1 to n2. But only the cloned line. My code changes on all lines containing n1. What am I doing wrong?

```
Body bod = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                    Table tables = bod.Descendants<Table>().First();
                    TableRow row = tables.Descendants<TableRow>().Last();
                    TableCell rowCell = new TableCell();
                    IEnumerable<FieldCode> placeHolder = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<FieldCode>();

                    // Denna tar fram TableProperties med namnet OrdeLines.
                    IEnumerable<TableProperties> tableProperties = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<TableProperties>().Where(tp => tp.TableCaption != null);
                    foreach (TableProperties tProp in tableProperties)
                    {
                        if (tProp.TableCaption.Val.Equals("OrderLines")) // see comment, this is actually StringValue
                        {

                            // do something for table with myCaption
                            Table table = (Table)tProp.Parent;
                            //Klonar sista raden
                            var cloneRow = table.ChildElements[3].CloneNode(true);
                            row.InsertAfterSelf(cloneRow);

                            foreach (TableCell tableCell in cloneRow)
                            { 
                                foreach (FieldCode code in placeHolder)
                                {   
                                    //var test = cloneRow.LastOrDefault().Where(x => x.InnerText == code.InnerText);

                                    var testo = tableCell.Parent.Descendants<FieldCode>().LastOrDefault().Where(X => X.InnerText == code.InnerText);

                                    if (testo != null)
                                    {
                                        code.Text = code.Text.Replace("n2_", "n1_");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

1):DOCPROPERTY  "MFiles_PGB5E4D5DC229C4027AB19B40D0203C01Cn1_PG3E2BB7EBC49E4C8C825CCAE0AEBA9A06"  * MERGEFORMAT

2):

[image]

3) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIZJ9.png)

```
        FieldCode fieldCode1 = new FieldCode(){ Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
        fieldCode1.Text = " DOCPROPERTY  \"MFiles_PGB5E4D5DC229C4027AB19B40D0203C01Cn1_PG3E2BB7EBC49E4C8C825CCAE0AEBA9A06\"  \\* MERGEFORMAT ";
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to be able to help you effectively. Field codes can be very complicated, and there are a lot of them. Could you use the [edit] link below the question to add: 1) the Word Open XML of the field codes (as text, not an image) and 2) an screen shot of the field codes in the document opened in the Word UI. (Use Alt+F9 in Word to toggle between field result and field code view.) That will tell use exactly what you're trying to work with; then we can better interpret the code you're using.

Comment: I can not show you a picture. But is there another way I can send that to you?

Comment: I see the picture, thank you... How about the underlying Word Open XML for the table row? You can get that by opening such a document in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool.

Comment: Mmmm, at least I know now how to start reading your code... `placeholder`is instantiated as `mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<FieldCode>();` - so *all the fields in the document*. You should instantiate it with all the fields in the range you want to change - so only the descendants in `cloneRow`.

Comment: I edit my question and I put 3) and picture there.

Comment: More like this (but this is just to give you the idea, I'm not sure the syntax as it stands works): `FieldCode placeHolder = cloneRow.Descendants<FieldCode>();`

Comment: When I instantiated all the fields. I wanted to go inside last Row cloneRow and change all FieldCode that has "n1" to n2.

Comment: The edit refers to the same picture as (2). But if you're trying to post XML it's better if it's text, not a picture.

Comment: I have found a solution. Thank you for taking your time.